# What's the activation function used in the nodes of hidden layer from nnet library in R?

Tags: r, neural-networks, nnet

Most references I find say that the activation function used in `nnet` is 'usually' a logistic function. But in the case that I would like to test the performance of the trained neural network from nnet, it is necessary to know the exact activation function used.

Answer (score 10):

This is the implemented function (extracted from the C-sources; file`nnet.c`, lines 156-165):

```
static double
sigmoid(double sum)
{
    if (sum < -15.0)
    return (0.0);
    else if (sum > 15.0)
    return (1.0);
    else
    return (1.0 / (1.0 + exp(-sum)));
}
```

Comment: Wonder why there is -15/15 limit, it is because it is faster to check for this condition than calculate `exp(15)`?

Comment: `1 / (1 + exp(- (15)))` is approx 0.999999694 and   `1 / (1 + exp(-(-15)))` is approx. 0.000000306 so they just choose to take the error. 15 seems pretty arbitrary, but fair.